# Open a particular activity on clicking on any link and get the data from URL

Tags: android

In my application, I need to open a particular activity and in that activity I need to get the data from the URL.
For example if user clicks on XYZ.com/userName/Address from browser or from any mail app, I want to open a screen in my application. And after opening that screen I need to get this userName and Address from this URL.

Is is possible? Can I get the URL in that activity and parse it

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you have to an `intent-filter` in your app that's how when the user will click on the particular link, android will ask the user whether open your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by deep-linking. As you like, you can get data from URL too.

For your reference:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

[Branch IO](https://branch.io/what-is-deep-linking/?bmp=androiddeeplinking&utm_campaign=BM-DeepLinking-India&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_term=androiddeeplinking&_bt=187105297860&_bk=deep%20linking%20android&_bm=e&_bn=g&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3MPNBRDjARIsAOYU6x9spSp7ClqgzJ-SNsFTPrsYMSlsBDKIjDfVgk2xjxvlq-LV3jsuaWkaAtZpEALw_wcB)

[Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)